# Is every finite Partially Ordered Set a Lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest Example of a Poset that is not a Lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112117/simplest-example-of-a-poset-that-is-not-a-lattice)

Question is simple

### Lattices

A Poset $(S,\leq)$ can be a Lattice if every pair of elements $a,b \in S$ in the Poset has a meet $\exists a \wedge b$ and a join $\exists a \vee b$.

### Question 1

Is my definition of lattice correct?

### Question2

Is every finite Poset a Lattice?

I guess no, but cannot find an example. Could you please make an example of Poset which is not a Lattice.

Comment: A poset with two elements and no nontrivial relations (a two-element antichain) is the minimal counterexample.

Comment: Really sorry for creating a duplicate, actually I searched under the lattice-orders label finding no other similar questions.

Answer (score 5):

Most posets are not lattices, including the following.
A discrete poset, meaning a poset such that x ≤ y implies x = y, is a lattice if and only if it has at most one element. In particular the two-element discrete poset is not a lattice.
Although the set $\{1,2,3,6\}$ partially ordered by divisibility is a lattice, the set $\{1,2,3\}$ so ordered is not a lattice because the pair 2,3 lacks a join, and it lacks a meet in $\{2,3,6\}$.
The set $\{1,2,3,12,18,36\}$ partially ordered by divisibility is not a lattice. Every pair of elements has an upper bound and a lower bound, but the pair 2,3 has three upper bounds, namely 12, 18, and 36, none of which is the least of those three under divisibility (12 and 18 do not divide each other). Likewise the pair 12,18 has three lower bounds, namely 1, 2, and 3, none of which is the greatest of those three under divisibility (2 and 3 do not divide each other).

Comment: Can one say - every TOSET is a lattice?

Comment: Yes, every TOSET is a lattice(even if it's unbounded). The Hasse diagram of TOSET is a linear chain, which implies every pair of elements is comparable. We know that for comparable elements least upper bound(LUB) and greatest lower bound(GLB) always exist.
Now since LUB and GLB exist for every pair of elements, it becomes a Lattice.